# Figure caption alignment problem

Tags: graphics, captions

I have a problem with the captions of my figures in a paper I am writing using the IOP template. I am using the usual package `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

And the LaTeX commands are

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width= 7.5cm,height=6cm]{figures/fig1.pdf}
\includegraphics[width= 7.5cm,height=6cm]{figures/fig2.pdf}
\caption[width = \textwidth]{Bla bla bla}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

which are pretty standard. The result I get is

[image]

As you can see the caption is not aligned with the figures, and it actually not even aligned with the text. What can I do?

Comment: Please include an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/30280), as it is rather impossible for us to see what you are doing wrong here (contrary to popular belief we don't have a crystal ball, unfortunately). Also, `\caption` does not take optional arguments, what you place inside `[ ]` (the short caption) is used instead of the long caption inside `{ } ` in the List of Figures.

Comment: This alignment is defined by the template and you should not try to modify it for this publication. As it is a template for a publication, you have to satisfy the publisher requirements

Comment: I am sorry hooy if I havant been clear. I was hoping this was a standard problem. And Yes you are right about the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width= 7.5cm,height=6cm]{figures/fig1.pdf}
  \includegraphics[width= 7.5cm,height=6cm]{figures/fig2.pdf}
  \caption[Second figure]{\lipsum*[2]} 
  \label{fig:1}  
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This was really helpful ! Now the captions are indeed allingned. I had to cancel the command \caption[Second figure]{\lipsum*[2]}  because my compiler did not recognize it, but the rest did the job perfectly. Deeply appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked ! you might not have the package installed, not so important though :)